# Problem with boost library ,What is the compiler flag here?

Tags: c++, boost

i've tried with `-lboost` `-lboost_lambda` `-lboost_lambda_lambda` every flag was wrong so i don't know what is the cflag right there...

source code

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 2};
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << "\n");
}
```

Comment: You probably need to provide a path to the libraries with the `-L` option.

Comment: Please don't use the C tag when there is nothing related to C in the Q. Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual error you get? Should be in the question.

Comment: i've removed the flag and now it works ...any knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost's lambda is a header only library and thus does not require any link-time action. Any time you supply something to the linker it can't find you are going to get an error, while if you provide something that isn't needed it will be silently ignored.

Comment: and what flag i need to add when i've this                                                      `#ifndef CHAT_MESSAGE_HPP
#define CHAT_MESSAGE_HPP

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>`

Comment: @G-programmer none, that's standard c++ headers

Comment: i've got a compiler error , my application is returning 1, it comes from these headers `#ifndef CHAT_MESSAGE_HPP #define CHAT_MESSAGE_HPP `

Comment: "if you provide something that isn't needed it will be silently ignored" - really depends on platform.  True on Windows - but on Linux, by default it will still insert a dependency to the dynamic library into the result, unless you use some flag like `-Wl,--as-needed` .